# How to delete row from VORA Table

Tags: vora

Is there any functionality to DELETE rows from a table, or even remove file from path list, or do I have to DROP the entire table and re-create it with the rows I need?

Also is there a TRUNCATE function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vora tables are based on files in HDFS. As of today (Vora1.2) you can only APPEND to an existing table. There is no DELETE or TRUNCATE functionality. You can however DROP the table and re-create it based on different files.

Comment: Is there a plan to implement such things?